# I am trying to figure out how to change a column of many dates so that any date that is "less than" 1/1/2021 will automatically change to 1/1/2021

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas, conditional-formatting, date

[image]

I have the conditional formatting set to change the color of the cell. But I need the actual value to change to 1/1/2021. But only if it's less than. If it's more than that, then I don't want it to change.

Answer (score 0):

#### Setting Dates

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, 9).getValues()
  const dt = new Date(2021, 0, 1);
  const dtv = dt.valueOf();
  let vo = vs.map(r => {
    if (new Date(r[8]).valueOf() < dtv) {
      r[8] = dt;
    }
    return [r[8]];
  });
  sh.getRange(2,9,vo.length,vo[0].length).setValues(vo);
}
```

Sheet0 Before:

[image]

Sheet0 After:

[image]